# Problem editing .bash_profile while installing Flutter on mac

Tags: bash, flutter, path

I am installing Flutter on my mac and I need to add a path in my .bash_profile file. But it already has contents in it and I do not want to mess up what i have. So how do i do this?

This is what is in my .bash_profile currently:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I need to add:

```
export PATH="/Users/rishika/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

in order to install Flutter

Please let me know how to go about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same way `PATH` was modified in the next-to-last line of your file.

```
PATH="/Users/rishika/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

The `export PATH` is likely unnecessary (though harmless); `PATH` is either inherited from the parent process or exported from a system file like `/etc/profile`, so already marked for export.

Comment: i dont understand. Could you maybe write the  whole code so i can copy paste it into my bash_profile. Sorry bout the hassle, i'm a newbie  >.<

Comment: I already did. In fact, looking at your question more closely, *you* already did. You just paste this line into your existing `./bash_profile`.